# What is the replacement for tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm() in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

It seems that TF 2.0 does not have `tf.contrib`. Then, what is the replacement for `tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm()`? I didn't find it in `tensorflow_addons` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement in the core TensorFlow 2.0 API is `tf.keras.lyaers.LayerNormalizaton()`.

Please see the documentation at: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization?version=stable.

Below is a simple usage example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=[20], activation="relu"))
# Here is the LayerNormalization layer.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.summary()

print(model.predict(np.ones([1, 20])))
```

Comment: The inputs to LayerNormalization() and layer_norm() are different. tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization() doesn't work. Read more about it here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization

Answer (score 0):

As everyone explained the new version of tensorflow above 2.0 does not support contrib. The simplest method to resolve this problem is go the file where it is showing error and change tf.contrib.layers to tf.keras.layers.
It worked for me.